# Dynamic laravel SQL query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a dynamic query with laravel whereby if certain conditions are met it will add to my query. Here is what I have attempted so far. Any guidance please?

```
    $Tasks = Task::leftJoin('task_recipients', 'tasks.task_id', '=', 'task_recipients.recipient_task_id');

    if ($filterAssignedToMe !== NULL) {
        $Tasks->where('task_recipients.recipient_user_id', '=', $user_id);
    }

    if ($filterAssignedByMe !== NULL) {
        $Tasks->where('tasks.created_by', '=', $user_id);
    }

    $Tasks->groupBy('task_id');
    $Tasks->get();
```

Comment: Doesnt give me any results

Comment: Ah I think I have answered my own question, I need to do $Tasks = $Tasks-get(); for some reason? Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: @amof This is the only way to to this if you want to get results back :) `->get()` for all matching results, `->first()` for the first matching result. If you don't use any of those, you only get a raw Collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$Tasks = Task::leftJoin('task_recipients', 'tasks.task_id', '=', 'task_recipients.recipient_task_id');

if ($filterAssignedToMe !== NULL) {
    $Tasks = $Tasks->where('task_recipients.recipient_user_id', '=', $user_id);
}

if ($filterAssignedByMe !== NULL) {
    $Tasks = $Tasks->where('tasks.created_by', '=', $user_id);
}

$Tasks = $Tasks->groupBy('task_id');
$Tasks = $Tasks->get();
```

Does this work?